# Deploying process is too slow using Capistrano, hang in precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

Env:
Ruby 2.6.3 / Rails 6.0 / Capistrano 3.14.1

Problem:
`cap production deploy` is very slow, almost 10 minutes. The log shows `$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile` takes about 8 minutes. I use the same comand and run it locally, it's very quick. So what is the problem and how to reslove it.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your dev machine is faster / has more RAM/CPU cores than your server.

Comment: I experienced this too... and ended up adding a lot of RAM on the server, which solved the problem. It is also possible to precompile on your dev machine and publish the precompiled js packs. I haven't seen any discussion about the pros/cons of doing that. It also means you don't need nodejs installed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the server performance limit & the solution is https://github.com/stve/capistrano-local-precompile if anyone is interested. It works well for me, which reduce the time to ~20 seconds.

Comment: It's a nice solution @Sefier Tang. But I'm curious why you rsync the compiled assets from your dev machine vs. publishing the compiled asset with the released code in the repo? With the rsync method, you pull the rails code from the repo, but the assets code straight from your dev machine, but they could easily be a different git versions, no? Maybe I'm missing something?